# Check content of a "range" within a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, range

I have a multidimensional array which is based on data from a spreadsheet. It is structured like this: `Array[0][row][column]`.

Now I want to check if the values in several rows within one column are blank. Is there a way to concisely express something like `if (Array[0][Row 1 to 10][Column 3] === "")` ?

This is my current code:

```
    function updateOverview() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();     
    var database = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XYZ');     
    var overviewContent = [ss.getDataRange().getValues()];     
    var campaignData = [database.getDataRange().getValues()];       

    for (var a = 1; a < (campaignData[0].length); a++) { 
     for (var d = 4; d < overviewContent[0].length; d++) {
       if (campaignData[0][a][3] === overviewContent[0][0][1] && (Utilities.formatDate(campaignData[0][a][7],"GMT+01:00","yyyyMMdd")) <= (Utilities.formatDate(overviewContent[0][d][3],"GMT+01:00","yyyyMMdd")) && (Utilities.formatDate(campaignData[0][a][8],"GMT+01:00","yyyyMMdd")) >= (Utilities.formatDate(overviewContent[0][d][3],"GMT+01:00","yyyyMMdd"))) {
         var campaignDuration = (Utilities.formatDate(campaignData[0][a][8],"GMT+01:00","yyyyMMdd") - Utilities.formatDate(campaignData[0][a][7],"GMT+01:00","yyyyMMdd"));
         var campaignSlotAvailable = true;  
           for (var b = d; b < (campaignDuration +1); b++) {
             if (overviewContent[0][b][5] !== "") {
               campaignSlotAvailable = false;
               break;
             }
          }
          if (campaignSlotAvailable) {
            overviewContent[0][d][5] === campaignData[0][a][6];
            }
          }
     }
   };        

    ss.getDataRange().setValues(overviewContent[0]);     
    };
```

Comment: Do you know about `for` loops?

Comment: Yes, it is all happening within a for loop.

Comment: I put in the code how I tried to solve it what unfortunately did not work